# ReactiveX, about mobile app architecture and layers

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift, reactive

I'm learning Rx (RxSwift in particular) and I have a question about architecture, layers and boundaries.

I'm used to layered architectures (data, domain, presentation), usually on MVP or VIPER. For this project I'm using MVVM, the recommended architecture for a Reactive app. These are my current collaborators:

```
**** Presentation ******************************************

                 ________________________
                |                        |
                |   GameViewController   |
                |                        |
                |      ____________      |
                |     |            |     |
                |     | BoardView  |     |
                |     |____________|     |
                |                        |
                |________________________|
                             |
                             |
                            \|/
                 ________________________
                |                        |
                |     GameViewModel      |
                |________________________|
                             |
**** Domain **************** | *****************************
                            \|/
                 ________________________
                |                        |
                |     GameController     |
                |________________________|
```

When the user taps (makes a move) the `BoardView` emits an event, which is being observed by the `GameViewController`, which calls a method in `GameViewModel` that communicates with `GameController` to check if the move is correct and then emits another event being observed by each one in the chain, and finally `BoardView` draws its stuff according to the correctness of the move.

My question is, is this flow correct? Do I have to stick to this way of doing things or there is a Reactive way that suits better? For example, maybe `BoardView` can talk directly to the view model without the view controller being involved, and there is not boundary breaking nor "violation of rules".

I'm a bit lost in terms of Rx better architectures, MVVM is simple but to make it SOLID you have to create more collaborators, and then the chain of observables could be a bit over-engineered.

Any help will be really appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a well written reactive app your logic will tend to be encapsulated in a number of stateless (static) functions rather than objects. Thus making your code more declarative.

As an example, your GameViewModel should accept a number of input observables that it will observe and produce a number of output observables for the views to subscribe to.

```
struct MyViewModel {
    let output: Observable<OutState> 
    init(input: Observable<InState>) {
        output = input.map {
            // transform input state into output state
        }
    }
}
```

Note in the above, that the transform is a pure function. Also note that the object itself is superfluous. It could as easily be a function:

```
func myOutput(input: Observable<InState>) -> Observable<OutState> {
    return input.map {
        // transform input state into output state
    }
}
```

That transform block could, of course, be a function itself.

```
func transform(in: InState) -> OutState {
}
```

Which is very easy to test and naturally encapsulates a particular use-case of your application.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for your answer :) I have a new question I'm sure you can answer again :D Any help will be really appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305554/rx-scan-cannot-generate-observable-from-seed-and-another-observable Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are going a data driven architecture (such as `MVVM`) you have multiple `Service` objects that fulfill your business logic. In the Rx world you subscribe to your service and service pushes `DTOs` into your controller where you map it into a `ViewModel`. I really recommend you look into `SOA` if you are going `MVVM` since `ViewModel` is only intended to be a decorator for `DTO` that can be accepted by different views. Your business logic should be contained in the services.

Rx is simply a collection of push interfaces and their transformations with time which allow your objects to be more encapsulated and self-sufficient. Instead of pulling data when controller decides, Rx methodology allows for your objects to provide that data when business logic requires. I don't think it's possible to define 100% fitting rules within `MVVM` or `VIPER` for every business logic scenario when using Rx. Just use common sense and see when it makes sense for your objects to push information upon recievers rather than pulling it at concerete times.

On a side note: I really recommend you stay away from any data driven object defining methodology (be it `MVVM` or `VIPER`). [Here is why](http://www.yegor256.com/2016/12/13/mvc-vs-oop.html).