# Rx scan(), cannot generate observable from seed and another observable

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have a seed value `Triangle (Bool)` and an observable that emits values `Circle (Int)`. My intention is to generate a new observable `(Triangle, Circle)`  each time a value is emitted from that observable, transforming the `Triangle` value negating the current value. This is my marble diagram:

[image]

But I cannot achieve it, and I don't know if `scan` is the correct operator. This is my code:

```
typealias Triangle = Bool
typealias Circle = Int

func scan() {
    let triangle: Triangle = false
    circleObservable
        .scan(triangle, accumulator: ({ (triangle, circle) -> (Triangle, Circle) in
            return (!triangle, circle)
        }))
}
```

This generates a compiler error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(Triangle, Circle) -> (Triangle,
>   Circle)' (aka '(Bool, Int) -> (Bool, Int)') to expected argument type
>   '(_, _) -> _'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
circleObservable.scan((Triangle(false), Circle()), accumulator: { lastValue, circle -> (Triangle, Circle) in (!lastValue.0, circle) })
```

Or simpler:

```
typealias Triangle = Bool
typealias Circle = Int

func scan(circle: Observable<Circle>) -> Observable<(Triangle, Circle)> {
    return circle.scan((Triangle(false), Circle())) { (!$0.0, $1) }
}
```

Comment: Uff, so simple, create the seed with a dummy Circle. Thanks again Daniel :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps 'throws' is missing? Have a look at this working example - https://github.com/maxvol/RaspSwift/blob/master/RaspSwift/RaspAggregator.swift